# URL Testing Tools API - How to Get more Responses options

Tags: google-apis-explorer

i was trying to implement the URL Testing Tools API, to get the scores about the requested website,
everything works fine expect that i want to get as result more details, not only enum type saying : Friendly or Not
how can i get more informations as "Loading Time" or "Est. Visitor Loss"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using this [google API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/reference/rest/v1/urlTestingTools.mobileFriendlyTest/run) which gives you very small amount of information and details (just as its [webiste version](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly)).

## Google pagespeed

If you want to get more information I suggest you to use [google pagespeed API](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v4/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed/) with device set to "mobile".

To do this you need:

### Get google pagespeed credentials to use pagespeed api

Go to [google api console](https://console.developers.google.com) (need to have google account).

Create new or choose existing project (list on top of page).

When in project Dashboard tab click "Enable APIs and services".

In search type "pagespeed" and enable this API.

Now go to project Credentials tab click "Create credentials".

Type of credentials depends on how you want to use api, eg. I use it in php web app with google library, so i choose "OAuth client ID" -> Web application and use credentials in JSON format. You can choose "API key" to generate one simple key to access api.

Now you have your credentials!

### Call pagespeed endpoint

#### cURL

Simpliest way to call this endpoint is by curl call:

@edit: change endpoint to newer version of api: v4

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url={url}&strategy=mobile&key={key}"
```

Where `{url}` is website url to test, and `{key}` is your "Api key" from project credentials.

You will get big JSON analyse result which needs to be parsed. It contain a lot of information which investigating I will leave to yourself.

#### Google libraries

Other way is using google libraries - if they exist for technology you are using. You can search for them on [github](https://github.com/google/)

#### PHP

For example I use [google php api](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) which allows to use pagespeed (and a lot other) api.

PHP snippet where `$credentials` are json credentials from google api console, and `$url` is examined url.

```
//Some initialization of google library instances.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setAuthConfig( $credentials );
$pagespeedService = new Google_Service_Pagespeedonline($client);
$pagespeedApi = $pagespeedService->pagespeedapi;

//Get pagespeed results.
$results = $pagespeedApi->runpagespeed($url, ['strategy' => 'mobile', 'screenshot' => true]);

//We even got image in base64!
$image = str_replace(array('_', '-'), array('/', '+'), $results->screenshot->data);
$imgHtml = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $image . '"/>';
```

P.S.

In future I suggest you to create more specific questions with links and/or tags so other people will easily find and understand your question.

Comment: I would like to thank you very much for your response that is very clear and easy to follow

Thank you

While waiting for a response i checked Internet and i found this solution you suggested but instead of using v2, i use v4
there's any difference between this two Version ? i suppose v4 will be more efficient

Comment: You are right, there is v4 of this API lately released, you can [read about it here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/release_notes). 
That was my old code snippet with v2, but eventhou its minor changes its better to use latest version, so use new v4.